# Agregate root vs child methods

Tags: domain-driven-design

I saw many different approaches and I am fairly new to domain-driven design approach. What I am struggling with is to understand one complex (at least for me) thing. I know the whole DDD is complex to understand on first but I am trying to find any resources I can on it.

Example: I have an order and order can have operations. Operations can not be accessed without order and they make no sense without an order. So order entity will be my aggregate root. Operations will be entity too because each operation will have an id (am I right on this one?). Each operation can have subitems (array of strings for example and these can be added or removed from any operation).

Now what I am struggling to understand and what I found everywhere is that every modification should be called and set only through aggregate root... But is it okay to have private methods like setters and getters on the Operation entity itself but these would be called only through the aggregate root (order entity)?

Sorry if I missed something basic, as the whole DDD concept for me is new and I am trying to explore it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of DDD concepts to arrive at the answer:

**Aggregates are Transaction Boundaries.**

Aggregates act as gatekeepers for all changes to domain elements enclosed within itself.
Data changes to an Aggregate and its enclosed domain elements are committed atomically. Either everything within the Aggregate stays in sync, or the whole state change operation fails.

The rule also means that one should not access Domain Elements within the Aggregate directly. It would be best if you did not manipulate the domain objects outside the context of the Aggregate.

If `Operation` is an entity under `Order` aggregate, then `Order` is responsible for ensuring operations satisfy the business invariants (a.k.a validations).

**Aggregates are loaded in entirety.**

Since an Aggregate represents the transaction and consistency boundary of a domain concept, its data is loaded in entirety to guarantee that all Business Invariants are satisfied. Data here means data of all underlying entities and value objects.

If you cannot load the entire data, you cannot guarantee that the change satisfies all business invariants. It may also mean that a data-intensive entity within the Aggregate may need to become an Aggregate itself.

---

You are protecting the data sanctity and operational consistency of the system if you adhere to these rules. Within the Aggregate itself, how you organize state changes is wholly left to you.

IMHO, I would go with your approach of enclosing all `Operation` related behaviors, data attributes, and invariants within the `Operation` entity. `Order` is responsible for protecting the data within its boundary, but it need not own the methods/logic of doing everything.

You can create state change methods within the `Operation` entity too, just like you would have done in the `Order` aggregate, but invoke them from the order object.

Comment: Awesome, this is a great explanation and it seems to be much more clear now. Thank you.